# Getting annotation attribute value from inside the method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I want to implement an audit trail in Spring-AOP. My problem is that I need to log the data that is created or retrieved from the method but not necessarily returned by the method. Right now, i'm using it on my controller, but that's not set in stone, i will need to put @Auditable in other methods.

```
@AuditableEvent(auditSeverity=AuditSeverity.INFO, data=???)
@RequestMapping("/createPerson")
public void createPerson(Model model){
     ...
     toBeLogged=service.createPerson();
     ...

     return somethingElse;
}
```

Here is the annotation declaration

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AuditableEvent {
    AuditSeverity auditSeverity();
    Object data();
}
```

Here is my aop declaration

```
@AfterReturning(value="@annotation(auditableEvent)")
public void logAuditActivity(JoinPoint jp, AuditableEvent auditableEvent){
      // save to database
}
```

I can't use the return value (for @AfterReturning) because it might be something else in the future. Searching the internet for answer so far, has only given me the option to use reflections, which is not pretty or might not even be advisable.

Comment: I don't understand the problem nor the code you posted. Please clarify.

Comment: what part do you not understand? I've made some edits.

Comment: What do you mean by _I can't use the return value (for @AfterReturning) because it might be something else in the future_?

Comment: If you're working with annotations, reflection is your only option (whether through Spring AOP or directly).

Comment: Also, what is the _data_ in _I need to log the data that is from the method_?

Comment: ahh, i see, what i mean is  "I need to log the data that is created or retrieved inside the method but is not necessarily returned by the method"

Comment: Reflection doesn't let you "look into" what a method is doing.